# Magento displaying multiple product lists on custom page

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom module to help profile my customers, for example I've captured data on my customers on what mobile phone they are using, and what's their favourite colour. Once collected they will land on a thank you page (e.g. /survey/mobile/thankyou) and I want to display products that can help customers out, so I want to display two lists, say a mobile phone cover and a recharging kit. I figured that you can call a product list with the following code on a phtml

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

I have 3 questions.

1. how do you pass a limit parameter to the list? say I want to display 3 products.
2. how do I past parameters to the list, e.g. phone_type = iphone/samsung?
3. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ The limit products in the list is set in the Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog

2/ To my opinion, if you want to pass params to the list, try to enable filter for the attributes you want to use in Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

3/ To me, the best way is create a custom block which extends class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List and write a loading list function there in order to meet your needs.

Comment: Not really answering my question based upon the above scenario. So there is no way to pass/set a value to limit the number of products to display on the list? How do you pass the filter? Is there an example to your Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List?

Comment: My answer for 1 + 2 from this: "http://<domain_name>/index.php/<rewrited_cat_url>?<attribute_code>=<value>&limit=8". It's a standard url of category page in magento

When you call it, the response collection will be exactly what you want